# What can be causing this weird soft keyboard bug on hide animation in my Android app using Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-animation, android-softkeyboard

I am clueless trying to figure out this weird bug. I even created a new clean project to try to reproduce it, but the new project does not present the issue in question.

Here the bug on soft keyboard hidding:

[image: Soft keyboard hidding annimation bug]

And here the expected behavior:

[image: Soft keyboard expected behavior]

Both example source codes are identical and where coded using Jetpack compose and kotlin. The only difference is that the buggy one comes from an existent project and the correct one is new from scratch, look at the code for reference.

```
package com.dummyapp.mydummyapplication

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.material.TextField
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
      TextField(
        value = "",
        onValueChange = { },
        // label = { Text(label) },
        placeholder = { Text("Introduce un texto") },
        singleLine = true,
        modifier = Modifier
          // .align(Alignment.Center)
          //.background(Color.White)
          .fillMaxWidth()
          .padding(horizontal = 0.dp, vertical = 0.dp)
          .background(Color.White)
      )
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Have you checked the difference between the old `AnroidManifest` and the new one?

Comment: So the code is the same but the behaviour changes between the two projects ?

Comment: @Niyas check below the solution

Answer (score 0):

If you remove this dependency, the bug is gone:

```
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-beta01"
```

adding it, and the bug appears. I still need to see how am I going to compile without that required classes.

Comment: I can confirm that switching down to
def nav_version = "2.6.0"
implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version"
fixes the soft keyboard bug too :D